# How do I create variable height rows of images based on the variable height of the images

Tags: css

Here are two links, one with horizontal images, the other with a mix of horizontal and vertical images. They both work off of the same css file. Thus each has the same fixed height for the divs that their images are in and that fixed height of 200px makes the spacing between rows in the first portfolio (horizontal images only) too much.

http://www.photoeye.com/gallery/forms2/index.cfm?image=1&id=195494&imagePosition=1&Door=2&Portfolio=Portfolio6&Gallery=2

http://www.photoeye.com/gallery/forms2/index.cfm?image=1&id=185363&imagePosition=1&Door=2&Portfolio=Portfolio13&Gallery=2&Page=

If I use height:auto; then it throws all of the images to the right (I don't understand why). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first image has height bigger than another images. And your div have float:left; css-rule. It means if you set height:auto; and if your images have different height, second row will be start after end of the image with biggest height (image №1 in you case).

Set `display:inline-block;` instead of `float:left;`

```
#Img_Container div {
   display: inline-block;
   height: auto;
   margin: 10px 7px 10px 10px; /*I change margin-right because inline-block elemets have margin-right:3px; by default */
   width: 150px;}
```

This link may help you with your second demo http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/images.html

Comment: Great! Thanks. I did have to put vertical-align: top; in order for it to align as before. Still can't get the two lines of text below the images to float with a fixed margin below the images. For some reason the text has to have a fixed padding-top:265px; in order to clear the images. Surely there is a better way.